# What is the origin of the names of the walls?

Tags: attack-on-titan

*Attack on Titan* has lots of Germanic features such as the music and wall names. In the case of the walls:

> "Rose" was the East Germany's secret codename plan to build the Berlin Wall.

Where does the other wall names Sina and Maria come from? Are there any references to the walls' names inside the story-line?

Comment: [Sina](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Sina) in latin means China. There was [Sino-German Co-operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sino-German_cooperation_until_1941)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/11682/6166